# Error while producing records via REST proxy in confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-rest-proxy

I am trying to produce AVRO/JSONSCHEMA record to confluent cloud REST proxy. Self managed REST Proxy server has been started pointing to confluent cloud, referring [this documentation.](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/cp-component/kafka-rest-config.html)

I am able to enlist topics, produce JSON records and consumer JSON records. But whenever I am trying to involve schema registry i.e. AVRO record or JSONSCHEMA record production, it is throwing  40801 ERROR.

For producing records, I referred [REST proxy quick start](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html#produce-and-consume-avro-messages)

REST call details :

```
POST /topics/new-tweet HTTP/1.1
Host: <aws-hostname>:8082
Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json
Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c97b6f48-f68e-f114-63d8-c2389ffd77f0

{"value_schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"User\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}", "records": [{"value": {"name": "testUser"}}]}
```

Error details:

```
{
    "error_code": 40801,
    "message": "Error when registering schema. format = AVRO, subject = new-tweet-value, schema = {\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the server logs?

Comment: No, as I mentioned its confluent cloud

Comment: The linked page is not a hosted Proxy, by the way, and it's not clear why they'd host that instead of forcing people through the ksql rest api... but, maybe contacting confluent support could be a next step. I don't see anything wrong with that request and the server would have a more descriptive stacktrace regarding the request error handling

Comment: even with ksql rest api I am unable to do list streams and list tables... just info is what I can see... I do not know if ksql rest api is supported by confluent cloud

Comment: Can you help me what can be the alternative solution?

Comment: Confluent Cloud does have KSQL; not sure what APIs are public, but they would have to be in order for the browser editor to make any queries to it. And yes, there is a [`LIST STREAMS`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/show-streams/) and tables query you can run. The "alternative" is run the REST Proxy on your own infrastructure, which is what the link you provided says to do